# Import a list of non-consumable Product as In App Purchases in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I can't seem to find a solution for this.

Do I really have to put in every Non-Consumable In App Purchase on its own?
Is there no way to load them from somewhere into iTunes Connect?

The only workaround I found was adding a currency to the app, and then letting the user buy currency and then the items. In that case I'd only need a few consumable In App Products.
But I don't know yet, if my company wants to do that.

Comment: Nope, every single in app purchase has to be created manually, with its own nice little screenshot *for review purposes*

Comment: Well, thanks. What do you think about the workaround?

Comment: We use that workaround as well, as do many others. It works.

Comment: It can work, but you will have to keep in mind that the restoration of the in app purchases when a user deletes the app and reinstalls it will then depend entirely on you.

Comment: well yes, but if every purchased item (bought with currency, not regular in app) AND the currency is stored on a server, from which I retrieve the data, that should not be a biggie.
Either the server processes a buy, so the user gets its item, or the server doesn't and the user does not lose any of his "coins".
Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I close this with my own answer.

I finally ended up using the workaround and it works pretty well!

I added a currency to the app, and then letting the user buy currency and then the items. In that case I'd only need a few consumable In App Products.

The company is very satisfied with this system, as they saw big marketing possibilities in it!

Thanks to @micantox and @simpleBob!